# iOS5: Relationship Segues and Tabs without using UITabBar

Tags: xcode, ios5, storyboard, uitabbar, segue

**TL:DR - How do I create Relationship Segues in Xcode 4.4?**

Hello everyone, I have an app where I want to add some tabbing behaviour to one of my controllers but, due to design decisions, I can't use UITabbar. I already know about using a UIToolbar with a UISegmented control inside it, but where I'm having difficulty, is how to switch between view controllers.

I know I can't use normal segues (since each tab change would keep stacking a new controller on top of the previous), but UITabBar has something called "Relationship Segues". I looked around but couldn't figure out how to create one.

Does anyone know how do it? Also, is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done the exact same thing recently. I've created a container view controller, SegmentedViewController, and added the view controllers I wanted to switch between to my container controller using `addChildViewController`. Upon switching view controller (I used target/action on my UISegmentedControl), you call `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animation:completion`. That's the general idea. Look at the "Implementing a Container View Controller" section [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for implementation details.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I can't test it right now but I read the section you mentioned and it's exactly what I wanted to do.